# Cannot locate JRE definition: "J2SE-1.8". Launch aborted

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I've just booted up a fresh install of Eclipse Neon, downloaded the latest versions of Xtext, Eclipse Facets and ANTLR 4, which gives me a full language and plugin compiler for Eclipse (using Xtext).

I have built my `mwe2` workflow for the **main** project, have clicked on the `plugin.xml` of the **ui** project, pressed "Launch an Eclipse Application" to test the grammar, and all of a sudden pops up a small box stating:

> Cannot locate JRE definition: "J2SE-1.8". Launch aborted."

Absolutely no stack trace or anything. Just this ambiguous line...

I am using this fresh install on my Windows computer, because the exact same error, word-for-word shows up on my Mac. I have my Java installed fine on both, using the latest versions of 1.8, so there must be something wrong with either Java itself, Xtext, or Eclipse.

What do I do!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in Xtext: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/issues/273

Workaround (1): Open generated launch config an replace `J2SE-1.8` with `JavaSE-1.8`
Workaround (2): Chose Debug, Debug Configureations ..., Debug (will autorepair the launch config)

Comment: Oh my god! Stupid issue, instant response, beautifully easy fix! Thankyou very much!